# Object not appearing on canvas body loads

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been attempting to program a start up section for my space invaders game. However, when the body loads one of my objects (the startbtn variable) is not appearing on the canvas.

Bellow is the code to my game

```
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>Space Invaders</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var startbtn;
    function startGame(){
            startbtn = new compenent(50, 20, "blue", 120, 10);
            myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {

        canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
        start: function(){
            this.canvas.width = 420;
            this.canvas.height = 220;
            ctx = this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, 
            document.body.childNodes[0]);
                ctx.font="35px Verdena";
                ctx.fillText("Welcome to Space Invaders",10,50);



            },
            clear : function(){
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width , 
                this.canvas.height);


            }

    }

    function compenent(width, height, color, x, y){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function(){
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }

    function updateGame(){
        myGameArea.clear();
        startbtn.update();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If someone could help me, that would be great.

Comment: You say:
    `startbtn.update();`
  then  `myGameArea.clear();` -- are you sure you want to clear the screen immediately after drawing?

Comment: Oh that must be the issue. I do not want to clear the canvas after drawing my startbtn.  That must've been the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I just put 'myGameArea.clear();' before 'startbtn.update();'  however it is still not appearing.

Comment: OK, that was just an idea. I recommend posting your HTML and the rest of your JS. Where are you calling these functions you've included here? Code looks similar to [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp) which uses a pretty funky (IMO) way of setting up the canvas. Are you attached to doing it that way?

Comment: That is the website which I am learning how to program the game from. Also, I will post the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `updateGame()` is never called. You can add it to the `startGame()` function to run after the canvas is set up. Having done this, the blue box shows but not the text. The reason is because `myGameArea.clear();` clears the text that was drawn in the `myGameArea.start` function. Removing `myGameArea.clear();` results in:

```js
var startbtn;

function startGame() {
  startbtn = new compenent(50, 20, "blue", 120, 10);
  myGameArea.start();
  updateGame();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 420;
    this.canvas.height = 220;
    ctx = this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,
      document.body.childNodes[0]);
    ctx.font = "35px Verdena";
    ctx.fillText("Welcome to Space Invaders", 10, 50);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width,
      this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function compenent(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

function updateGame() {
  //myGameArea.clear();
  startbtn.update();
}

startGame(); // moved from body.onload
```

However, at this point, it may be clear that there are some potential design obstacles ahead in making a full-featured space invaders game. The w3schools tutorial you're using is attempting a basic [entity-component system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system), but this might be confusing for starters, so I'd encourage you to poke around at other tutorials for context if nothing else.

As your example is moving towards, animations have basic parts:

1. initialization routine (create objects and set initial positions for everything)
2. update routine (reposition objects, calculate collisions and damage)
3. rendering routine (draw the frame)

The init runs one time, or in some cases whenever an animation (or game level) needs resetting. The update and rendering routines run many times a second and together constitute the main animation loop (each one executes once per frame, so they're essentially parts of the same "animation loop" function):

```
              ----------------
              |              |
              v              |
init -----> update -----> render
```

This requires that each routine be responsible for their task and nothing else. Every call to render should clear the screen, then draw each and every visible object. The init function shouldn't have any rendering code, for example.

Also worth mentioning: everything being drawn is an object (or entity). W3schools' tutorial gets you started on this path, but how are you going to distinguish a `button` component from a `spaceInvader` component? You might just make them separate [objects/classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) entirely for starters.

The next level of abstraction is a state, each state with its own  `init --> update --> render` functions:

```
 ----------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------- 
 |             menu state               |    |             game state               |
 |                                      |    |                                      |
 |                 ----------------     |    |                 ----------------     |
 |                 |              |     |    |                 |              |     |
 |                 v              |     |    |                 v              |     |
 |   init -----> update -----> render   |    |   init -----> update -----> render   |
 ----------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------
```

What does all of this mean for your example? You're attempting to set up a menu state with some text and a button to begin the game. Managing a bunch of game states can get pretty complex, so graphics libraries like [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) offer [built-in state management systems](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2014/08/28/phaser-tutorial-understanding-phaser-states/). You can design one if you wish or postpone the problem and use a variable or boolean to determine which state you're in. For starters, I recommend working in a single state, then adding more when necessary. In other words, consider simplifying or skipping the menu state in favor of the game state until you're ready to work with states.

Another potentially challenging aspect of doing animations is handling mouse events. How do you know when your button was clicked on? At the least, you'll need to use an [event listener and some math](https://blog.lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8). Libraries can [do it for you](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Stage_Events.html).

Either way, getting your loop [going](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/05/Two-Ways-of-Creating-an-Animation-Loop-in-JavaScript/) in JS will require [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or (less likely/recommended) [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Check out some [basic examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) from the MDN web docs.

I hope this helps offer a path forward and highlights some areas you may want to look into before going too much further with your current approach.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for basic tutorials for js games for people at my level? Or any frameworks and engines I can use for js game design.

Comment: It might be a bit outdated, but the first one I tried was from MDN: [breakout in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript). There's quite a few libraries like the aforementioned Phaser, [and others](https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines), but I recommend starting with vanilla and building up like you're doing. In this answer, I'm mainly trying to give an overview of the various challenges ahead--pick one or two and work on simple examples and eventually you'll have picked up all the tools to make whatever you want.

Comment: I know this is completely off topic however, I was currently about to post a new question when a blank page with just text popped up blocking me from asking my question, stated that with my only question, I have a history of asking bad questions. If there is any way someone can help please comment how.

Comment: @Ameer I'm not sure (never asked a question), but search/ask on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).